# Zooming on click of large image to the coordinates of the click

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming

So I have a large jpg, 12000px wide by 1000px height. I am looking to make a site the has the image at 50% size on page load, but when the user clicks on the image once, it zooms in to 100%, then on a second click, it zooms back out to original size.

Since the size of the image is so large, it would need to be draggable at both page load and during zoom state.

I have been playing around with this, but the code is not exactly what I am looking to do.

http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/jQueryZoom/ZoomTest.html

Instead, I am looking to basically do the same thing as the zoomed in state of this site, minus the step of the click into the zoom state.

http://yogasmoga.com/women/run-jump-n-play-crop-462

If anyone has a plugin they have used, please let me know.

Comment: not a good idea to put an image that big on the site

Comment: It's for a presentation, so it won't be for public use

Answer (score 0):

Don't. Easiest -especially if it's for a presentation- is to just use two images. image1.onclick -> show image2; image2.onclick -> show image1. Saves coding, does what you want.